# Stop vue filter / javascript when condition is met

Tags: javascript, vue.js, logic

Javascript / Vue n00b. Want to write a filter that formats a value that is a 1 - 3 digit number. I want a 1 digit number to change to '#00X', 2 digit number to '#0XX' and 3 digit to '#XXX'. So far I have this:

```
//Vue Filter

Vue.filter('number_filter', function (value){
  if(value.length === 1){
    value = value.toString()
    return '#00' + value;
  }else if(value.length === 2){
    value = value.toString()
    return '#0'+ value;
  }else{
    value = value.toString()
    return '#' + value;
  }
});
```

The filter will take 'X' and return '#X' because it doesn't break when the first condition is met. What can I do?

Comment: Use `String(value).length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and avoid the `if/else`:

```
Vue.filter('number_filter', function (value){
    return '#' + value.toString().padStart(3, '0');
});
```

**In your original code**, the `value` is of `Number` type and you are checking on `length` property on `Number` which will always be `undefined`, you need to convert it to `string` first and then check on value:

```
Vue.filter('number_filter', function (value){
  value = value.toString();
  if(value.length === 1) {
    return '#00' + value;
  } else if(value.length === 2) {
    return '#0'+ value;
  } else {
    return '#' + value;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it:

```
Vue.filter('number_filter', function (value){

  value = value.toString()
 
  if(value.length === 1){
    return '#00' + value;
  }
  if(value.length === 2){
    return '#0'+ value;
  }
    return '#' + value;
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
 Vue.filter('number_filter', function (value){
     return "#"+"0".repeat(3 - value.length)+value.toString();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879691/get-number-of-digits-with-javascript) regarding how to get the number of digits.

Also, based on your question, unless there's an overlying condition that stops someone from entering a number that contains more than 3 digits, then you're output could end being something like "#3051". You would need another else-if to check for number of digits === 3.

Answer (score -2):

The `String` method `padStart` will do for your requirement. It will add `0` for 2 digits and rest will be returned as it is.

```
Vue.filter('number_filter', function (value){
 return '#' + value.padStart(3, 0)
});
```