# A small issue with javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a simple fuzzbuzz in javascript (see below). I however would like to include the following:

- if the number starts with a 1 (so fe 11) "ping" should be added. So 15 should be FizzBuzzPing etc...

Any thoughts?

```
function fizzBuzz() {

   for (var i=1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
      if (i % 15 == 0)
          alert("FizzBuzz");
      else if (i % 3 == 0)
          alert("Fizz");
      else if (i % 5 == 0)
          alert("Buzz");
      else
         alert(i);
   }
}


$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#clickMe').click(function(){
      fizzBuzz();     
   });  
});
```

Comment: Convert the number to a string and test the first character? Also, should "Ping" be output for _all_ numbers that start with a 1, or just the numbers that already have some other output because they match one of the other conditions?

Comment: "Any thoughts?" --- add it.

Comment: what effort have you made to solve your new problem, not just what you have done.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry missed the line about "Ping" , what is required thing please explain I cannot comprehend it.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to a string and take the first index of the string:

```
var digit = (''+i)[0];
```

Or, the alternative

```
var digit = i.toString()[0];
```

Then check if digit is equal to 1 or not and add things or not accordingly.

For a future reference: Spend some time *searching* for a solution to your problems, don't *ask* questions unless you've spent some time *making sure* an answer does not exist to your question. A *similar* question has been answered many times before. Maybe it's not about fuzzbuzz but you should be able to find two different answers to two different questions and be able to combine then into your solution.

Comment: Btw, it's a strange decision to use tricky `('' + int)` conversion when a nice and readable `.toString()` is available.

Comment: @zerkms Some will [disagrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955738/javascript-get-the-second-digit-from-a-number) with you but sure it's an alternative, just a matter of preference. Added it to the answer nevertheless :)